# Sharepoint Search Server 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

Can someone point me in the right direction please.  i'm trying to use Search Server Express 2010, which uses Sharepoint 2010.  I would like to use this from within my own webpage and output the results within my site. Using .Net & C#.

I have attempted to use the webservice but get "Attempted to perform and unauthorized operation" as an error.  I'm also attempting to use the srchrss.aspx page to output my results but getting a 401 error.  Could someone point me in the right direction with an example please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wish you had've got a reply to this. +1 for good question.